# WebApi 2 POST result for Edit operation

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, hateoas

In my WebApi 2 service i have a controller which allows to edit member data.

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Members/Member")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> EditMember([FromBody] Member editedMember)
    {
        var member = await _membersRepository.GetMembersById(editedMember.MemberId);

        if (member == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        member = await _membersRepository.EditMember(editedMember);

        Uri locationHeader = new Uri(Url.Link("MemberById", new { id = editedMember.MemberId }));

        return Ok();
    }
```

According to HATEOAS i should return an URI of the resource i POSTed to. I would think that the correct result if everything went well is OK. But it does not allow to include the URI in it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is this:

`return Ok( new { locationHeader });`